expect_out(buffer) returns (buffer)
I have this strange behavior which i can't find anything on.
expect -re "\$remote_cert_dir.+crt" {
    set last_cert $expect_out(buffer)
}
puts "after expect \$last_cert"

Gives the output:
after expect (buffer)
I cant get my head around why this even is possible, it like the expect_out returns it's own parameters.

Why are you escaping the $ in the first line but not the second? If you are embedding expect code in a bash script, I find it safest to use a quoted heredoc.

Firstly - thanks that fixed it, I would have sworn I did try that..

So based on your answer, this is not in fact an expect script, but is a portion of a shell script that is passed to expect (perhaps via expect -c " ... " or via expect -f -)? If so, please [edit] your question to make that clear so that readers have enough context to understand why the answer works.

As Glenn writes, just escaping the $expect_out variable fixes the problem.
I changed
set last_cert $expect_out(buffer)

to
set last_cert \$expect_out(buffer)

Also this is a snippet I am using quoted heredoc.
